# How to get lookup fields attachment in pnp js sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-js-core

I would like to get lookup fields attachments url. For example

### Doctor

Id
EmployeeId(Look up)
Attachments

### Employee

Id

EmployeeName

Attachments (need to get)

How can I get Employee list's attachments from calling doctor lists and expand employee ?

Comment: If you can post what pnpjs code you have tried so far, they would help us diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's not possible to get the attachment of the referenced list item from calling doctor lists in one request. Attachment is a navigation entity that is attached to the item. It's not an expanded property.

I suggest you send a second request to the target item with the lookup id. Or you can try below endpoint if your lookup column is single-value type.

```
/_api/Web/Lists(guid'765')/items(1)/lookup/AttachmentFiles
```

BR